# How do I prevent image clipping from enlarging images?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a gallery where clicking an image would enlarge it, and clicking it again reverts it back to its original size. as of right now, enlarging an image will clip into subsequent images if those images have also been clicked on.

This is my html

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Source of Image</th>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Need For Speed Heat</th>
            <div id="enlarge">
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img1)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img1"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img2)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img2"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img3)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img3"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img4)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img4"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img5)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img5"></td>
        </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Reality</th>
            <div id="enlarge">
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img6)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img6"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img7)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img7"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img8)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img8"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img9)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img9"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img10)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img10"></td>
        </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sketches</th>
            <div id="enlarge">
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img11)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img11"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img12)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img12"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img13)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img13"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img14)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img14"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img15)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img15"></td>
        </div>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

This is my javascript

```
let enlarged=0;
        function toggleEnlargeImg(img) {
     if (enlarged===0){
        document.getElementById("enlarge").style.zIndex = "999";
        img.style.transform = "scale(2.5)";
       img.style.transition =
       "transform 0.25s ease";
       enlarged = 1;
     }
     else{
        document.getElementById("enlarge").style.zIndex = "1";
       img.style.transform = "scale(1)";
       img.style.transition =
       "transform 0.25s ease";
       enlarged = 0;
     }
     return enlarged;
  }
```

I tried to use zindex to forcefully change the layering but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm still very new to this.

I tried to use zindex to forcefully change the layering but it doesn't work. I think a if else statement is probably the key to fixing this but I'm not sure how to implement it(that's what the ensmalling in my html was supposed to be for). Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm still very new to this.

Comment: Elements in an HTML document should not have duplicate `id` attribute values.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't use the same id's for two different elements. I changed it to `img.style.zIndex` and it works fine. Next, you have to put in your JavaScript with `img.style.position = 'relative'` or `img.style.position = 'sticky'` which both work fine, I used `relative` in my code. If you don't set the position style it won't work.

```js
let enlarged=0;
        function toggleEnlargeImg(img) {
     if (enlarged===0){
        img.style.position = 'relative'
        img.style.zIndex = '999';
        img.style.transform = "scale(2.5)";
       img.style.transition =
       "transform 0.25s ease";
       enlarged = 1;
     }
     else{
        img.style.zIndex = '1';
       img.style.transform = "scale(1)";
       img.style.transition =
       "transform 0.25s ease";
       enlarged = 0;
     }
     
     return enlarged;
  }
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Source of Image</th>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Need For Speed Heat</th>
            <div>
            <td><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1707343843437-caacff5cfa74?q=80&w=1375&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img1)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img1"></td>
            <td><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1709730185387-9cac9f8e30e5?q=80&w=1374&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img2)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img2"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img3)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img3"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img4)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img4"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img5)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img5"></td>
        </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Reality</th>
            <div>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img6)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img6"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img7)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img7"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img8)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img8"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img9)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img9"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img10)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img10"></td>
        </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sketches</th>
            <div>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img11)" onclick="focusImg()" id="img11"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img12)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img12"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img13)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img13"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img14)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img14"></td>
            <td><img src="images/0016.jpg" alt="" width="100%" onclick="toggleEnlargeImg(img15)" onclick="ensmallImg()" id="img15"></td>
        </div>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Ok I fixed that.